# How to output a euro sign in C++

Tags: c++

I trying to output a eurosign for a program that calculates taxi fare and then offers to convert it into either dollars or euros.
Part of the specification is that I MUST output a eurosign. i have tried Unicode but I'm not having any luck. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here's my code:

```
void produceFareInOtherCurrency(){
//Constant variable for eurosign
const char EUROSIGN = 128;

//Selects currency
switch (currency)
{
//Euros
case 'E':
price = price * 1.1;
cout << "Cost in euros is: " << price << EUROSIGN << ".\n\n";
break;

//Dollars
case '$':
price = price * 1.22;
cout << "Cost in US Dollars is: $"<< price << ".\n\n";
break;

//Exit
case '#':
break;

//Error message
default:
cout << "ERROR: Currency unknown!\n\n";
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have a European keyboard? Then there is most likely a Euro sign somewhere on it. Usually together with the `E` key, try pressing `Alt-Gr` and `E` to see what you get. If you don't have a Euro key, then [the Unicode Euro symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) is not encoded as `128` in any encoding.

Comment: What OS are you using?  You need to make sure that the console supports unicode characters

Comment: I'm using windows 10, and I have a British keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has limited support for printing Unicode in console. In Visual Studio you can use `_setmode` to print Unicode symbols:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"€\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you have to call `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT)` if you intend to use `std::cout` again.

If using MinGW, use the following instead:

```
#include "windows.h"

void myprint(const wchar_t* str)
{
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), str, wcslen(str), NULL, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    myprint(L"€\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In Linux you may simply try

```
std::cout << "€\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the unicode character literal for the euro sign : \u20AC

```
cout << "Cost in euros is: " << price << "\u20AC.\n";
```

Edited as noted in the comments

Comment: I keep getting the same problem, it outputs an C with an accent underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
#include <windows.h>
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
cout << (char)(128);
```