# Getting WCHAR array to std::string in unicode?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, wchar

I'm doing on a win32 application, and has a edit control that accepts unicode text input. I use the following code to get the text to a `std::string`:

```
WCHAR out[50] = {};
GetDlgItemTextW(hwnd, ID_Edit, out, 50);
wstring myWString(out);
string myString(ws.begin(), ws.end());
```

In the dubugger, I can see that `myWString` is fine when input is unicode text, but `myString` is currupted.

How can I convert it correctly?

**EDIT:**

OK, rather then fooling with `string`, I use `wstring` instead.
But another problem arise:

I have another code that was using `string`, `cout` and `cin` to get user input in consle, now `wstring`, `wcin` and `wcout` breaks the non-ASCII text input and out put part...

For my code it was:

```
string myString;
//...
cin >> myString;
//...
cout << myString;
```

Changing to:

```
wstring myString;
//...
wcin >> myString;
//...
wcout << myString;
```

The input and output text are corrupted if the user use non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Why do you want to convert in the first place? If you need to work with internationalized, non-ASCII text, use `wstring` for it.

Comment: You can use WideCharToMultiByte  API

Comment: This question is too broad without knowing the source and destination encoding.

Comment: @MrEricSir: Since it's coming from GetDlgItemTextW, the source encoding is UTF16. But the destination encoding is important.

Comment: If using Visual Studio, you need [_setmode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9051543/4603670). Or see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40626557/4603670) for other compilers. Or just use `MessageBoxW` for Windows programming. You may want to define `UNICODE` in your project so that Windows API functions will default to `UNICODE` (`W` version)

Answer (score 0):

OK, after google around, I can finally using cin and wstring together without unicode problem.
I add the lines:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
wcin.imbue(locale(""));
wcout.imbue(locale(""));
```

and the wcin is good now:

```
wstring myString;
getline(wcin, myString);
//...
wcin >> myString;
//...
wcout << myString;
```